# Arabic & English text problem in Galaxy S and Nexus S in TextView

Tags: android, textview, arabic, galaxy

With a `TextView` with right gravity when I write a mix of English and Arabic texts, some English texts are moved to the right of the `TextView` and are not shown.

This may be because of some sort of arabizer in Samsung.

Any suggestions to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTL language support is only partially implemented in Android 2.3. This may be one of the limitations. Try it in a 2.3 emulator (to see if this is specific to Samsung, as you suggest) and a 3.0 emulator (to see if this has been improved).